# Are questions about durability and/or resistance of android devices and the materials used (like gorilla glass, SD cards, batteries) offtopic?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about durability of android devices and the materials used (like gorilla glass) offtopic?

I know that asking for battery durability (how long battery needs to be replaced instead of how long a charge lasts) is not.

There are also several questions on SD card rewrites.

Also questions on [screen resistance](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=resistance%20screen).

Comment: I'd say all of them are kind of "gray area". While most SD card and battery questions are behavior-oriented (how to use your Android device), especially material-properties are at least very dark. What makes gorilla glass special is definitely no Android question, for example – and you should handle your device with care no matter what. I'm afraid, a clear "yes" or "no" to this question is not possible, all depends on context.

Comment: I'm going to disagree with Izzy.  I think the answer is yes, they are off topic.  I don't see a special reason to allow questions about other parts but not batteries.  And I think the same reasoning applies -- most answers will be opinion and relatively Android-independent.  Our expertise is usage, not the tolerances etc. of electronics.

Comment: Can someone give me an answer I can vote on? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77900/marking-comment-as-an-answer

Comment: @Mindwin there you go :)

Answer (score 2):

By the letter, they are off-topic as being "Android independent hardware questions" – as Matthew correctly pointed out with his comment on the question itself. However, "by the letter" that would also apply to several of our [battery-life](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-life) and [battery](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery) questions (e.g. [When should I start charging my Lithium battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4003/16575)).

While I originally held the context might make a difference, that's hard to find for material durability – while with the battery example, it falls into "daily use of your Android device" (maybe into a gray zone, though).

So I tend to follow Matthew's reasoning, declaring such questions (as described by the question above) off-topic.